# Mysql driver extension to perl not getting installed

Tags: perl, windows-7, wamp

I installed perl on windows 64bit WAMP installation using the following [link](http://www.chromicdesign.com/2009/05/setting-up-perl-for-wampp.html)

> E:\wamp\bin\perl\bin>ppm repo add uwinnipeg ppm repo failed:
>   constraint failed repo.packlist_uri may not be NULL

So whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI for the repo is missing. See the [documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.14/bin/ppm.html) for the correct syntax.

Comment: I didnt understand, sorry i am just a begineer in perl. Can u elaborate?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl per se. You're not using the `ppm` program correctly.